# Find the maximum value of the plane when it intersects with the cylinder

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have not seen maximum and minimum values in multivariable calculus, but my teacher, but my teacher left as an exercise.

Let

$x+y+z=1$ and $4x^2+9y^2=6$

Find the maximum value of the plane when it intersects with the cylinder.

Could you help me..

methods

Comment: It's somewhat clear what "the maximum value" is here. Is it the $z$-value? $x$-value? $y$-value? or the value of some other function?

Comment: Cylinder? $4x^2 + 9y^2 = 6$ is an ellipse.

Comment: @Phil H the z becomes a free variable in this case and what we are left with is an elliptical cylinder. Think of it as that particular ellipse on the xy plane then stretch it out forever in the positive and negative z-direction.

Comment: Ah yes, I remember now being similarly confused a long time ago by an x,y equation as a 3D object.

Comment: The formulation of this question reveals a lousy attitude.

Answer (score 2):

Take note that the second equation acts more of like a boundary. So what we could alternatively say is to find the maximum of $f(x,y) = 1-x-y$ on the domain of $4x^2 + 9y^2 = 6$.

Note that we can define the ellipse parametrically as $$x=\sqrt{\frac32}\cos{\theta} $$

$$y= \sqrt{\frac23} \sin{\theta}$$

$$\text{For } 0\le \theta \le 2\pi$$

Now all that is needed to be done is substitute these $x$ and $y$ into $f(x,y)$ to get a new equation $$g(\theta) = 1 - \sqrt{\frac32}\cos{\theta} - \sqrt{\frac23} \sin{\theta}$$

This now becomes a single variable calculus problem, as we now want to find where $g'(\theta) = 0$

This is going to find you your maximum AND minimum, so make sure that once you found your values for $\theta$ you find the corresponding $x$ and $y$ values and plug these into $f(x,y)$ to see which is the maximum and which is the minimum.

I'll let you use this setup to see if you can continue from here :)